# Weird symbol at the end of strings when drawn to the screen

Tags: c++, string, sfml

I'm working on a game with a dialogue box that has text show up while you're reading it, like in an RPG. I got it to work, but my one problem is when I draw it to the screen there's a weird symbol I didn't type in and isn't on the keyboard. I have a gif below to demonstrate.

[image: Failed Dialogue Gif]

Here's my code:

TextRenderer.h

```
#ifndef TEXTRENDERER_H
#define TEXTRENDERER_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

class TextRenderer {
    public:
        Texture *t;
        Sprite sprite;
        string currentString, fullString, eBeforeString;
        int currentWordNum, onTheLine;
        vector<string> words;
        Text drawableText;
        Font font;
        Clock charTime;
        TextRenderer();
        void update();
        void newText(string nText);
};

#endif // TEXTRENDERER_H
```

TextRenderer.cpp

```
#include "TextRenderer.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace sf;
using namespace std;

TextRenderer::TextRenderer() {
    t = new Texture;
    t->loadFromFile("data/images/talkScreen.png");
    sprite.setTexture(*t);
    sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getGlobalBounds().width/2, 0);
    sprite.setScale(4, 4);
    font.loadFromFile("data/fonts/VCR_OSD_MONO_1.001.ttf");
    drawableText.setFont(font);
    drawableText.setFillColor(Color::White);
    drawableText.setCharacterSize(30);
    currentWordNum = 0; /// Initializing variables
    currentString = "";
    eBeforeString = "";
}

void TextRenderer::update() {
    /// If the current word number (spot in the words vector) is less than
    /// the size of the words vector
    if (currentWordNum < words.size()) {
        if (currentString.length() < words.at(currentWordNum).length()) {
            if (charTime.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= 0.02) {
                currentString = words.at(currentWordNum).substr(0, currentString.length() + 1);
                charTime.restart();
                onTheLine += 1;
            }
        } else if (currentString == words.at(currentWordNum)) {
            /// If you just finished typing a word
            if (charTime.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= 0.02) {
                eBeforeString += currentString + " ";
                currentString = "";
                currentWordNum += 1;
                onTheLine += 1;
                if (currentWordNum != words.size()) {
                    if (onTheLine + words.at(currentWordNum).length() >= 53) {
                        eBeforeString += "\n";
                        onTheLine = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    drawableText.setString(eBeforeString + currentString);
}

void TextRenderer::newText(string nText) {
    fullString = nText;
    /// Breaking the string into 'words' which I add to a vector
    char eStr[fullString.length()];
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < fullString.size(); i++) {
        eStr[i] = fullString.at(i);
    }
    char *spt = strtok(eStr, " ");
    while (spt != NULL) {
        words.push_back(spt);
        spt = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    currentString = "";
    eBeforeString = "";
    currentWordNum = 0;
    onTheLine = 0;
    drawableText.setString(currentString);
    drawableText.setPosition(sprite.getPosition().x + 20 - sprite.getGlobalBounds().width/2, sprite.getPosition().y + 10);
    charTime.restart();
}
```

And in main.cpp, I just call

```
textScreen.newText("Look at the symbol at the very end of this string on the other side of this period .");
```

Comment: `strtok` is old-style C code and is just generally annoying to use. Have you considered using a `std::istringstream` instead? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream When you read a string from it, it will be separated on whitespace.

Comment: Maybe like this: http://pastebin.com/fF1GZAJ2

Comment: @quetzalcoatl the `cout` line just writes "Success! " because nothing happens yet when the algorithm is done. I checked the `Node` equality operator I wrote just now and there weren't any noticable bugs, it just returns `position == otherNode.position`

Comment: alright.. so assuming that `while` never breaks and that `return` in if(end) never returns, then how do you know that the algorithm works and that it has found the solution? or maybe you actually see the "Success" in the console output?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Yeah, the only way I know it's done is if it outputs "Success", and if it doesn't, it goes on indefinitely. I also made it so it's impossible for it to not be able to find what it's looking for becuase the algorithm goes through walls.

Comment: Hm. I played a bit with that to make it compile. I had to kick out the sort-by-fscore function, and stub some struct definitions, but it seems to work: https://ideone.com/nR3mWy (re original:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394806/why-doesnt-this-a-algorithm-work)

Comment: Of course, since you did not provide any interesting input cases, the case I've chosen may simply be lucky.. I tried 5 times, all 5 returned results. As I said, I had to change a few things. I provided my own ==operators, I changed 'neighbours' and 'position' in Node to be based on Position, not Vector2i (strange idea.. how did you manage to compile that?), and also please check out the Node.operator== - I intentionally removed `a.parent==b.parent` test because it would probably make the algorithm never end since all parents for new nodes will never be the same as for old nodes..

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Vector2f is used for coordinates in SFML, and so I used Vector2i instead because I wanted the nodes not to support floats. I think I may have figured something out. The player starts at the position (6, 6). When I tried debugging it by printing off all the nodes to see what the algorithm was doing, they always went for the position (6, 6), even though the player had moved to (2, 7). Could I be passing an old copy of the player? Is that even possible?

Comment: Oh, so vector 2i is simply x,y pair

Comment: Well. ok. But that doesn't change anything. I updated my example on https://ideone.com/nR3mWy and it still works. Please, check your Node.operator== and see if it compares `parent`s.

Comment: If it does compare parents, then the last loop and two `find`s (find node in closednodes, find node in opennodes) will most probably never find anything in neither list, because you always have new nodes and the 'current' used as 'parent' is always different than in previous loop iteration..

Comment: You never said anything about `g,f` in Node.. I have no idea what's that. You only said that Node contains `Start location, end location, position and parent Node` and that's what I used in my example on ideone. About `positions` I meant to **NOT COMPARE** it. Don't add comparing them.. that's almost pure nonsense. Only **position** should be compared unless you have some strange multi-path algo, and in that case start/end could be compared as well (thus I kept that in the example), but parents - never. Sorry, it's 2AM here, I have to disappear now. Good luck!

Comment: @quetzalcoatl thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1201ProgramAlarm's answer solves the immediate problem, but I have a different view.

`strtok` is a holdover from C. It has its uses, but it requires you to leave the comfort of `std::string` for the wild and woolly world of c-strings and either dynamic allocation or the non-standard [Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) used by OP. It also has potential failure cases that stem from being written to handle simpler problems from simpler times. For example, all `strtok`s use the same internal buffer. The obvious threading implications have been solved with thread-local storage, and the remaining problem of two or more concurrent `strtok`s in one thread is solved with `strtok_r` (re-entrant `strtok`), but seeing as we are coding in C++, we might as well handle this with C++ streams.

Instead may I suggest

```
void TextRenderer::newText(string nText) {
    fullString = nText;

// replacement starts here
    istringstream in(nText);
    string word; 
    while (in >> word) {
        words.push_back(word);
    }
//end replacement

    currentString = "";
    eBeforeString = "";
    currentWordNum = 0;
    onTheLine = 0;
    drawableText.setString(currentString);
    drawableText.setPosition(sprite.getPosition().x + 20 - sprite.getGlobalBounds().width/2, sprite.getPosition().y + 10);
    charTime.restart();
}
```

This completely eliminates the need for `eStr` (which pains me because I like the egg hunt) and reduces the code to an easy to read 5 liner.

[Documentation on istringstream.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)

Comment: 1201ProgramAlarm's answer worked for me, but I still want to learn this one. It didn't compile for me, basic_istringstream in(nText) didn't work. Was your code pseudo or literal?

Comment: @Merle Attempt at literal. Obviously I couldn't compile it all because I don't have `TextRenderer`. Give me a minute to see if I missed anything stupid.

Comment: I didn't mention a need for an extra include: `#include <sstream>`

Comment: I forgot to reply, I got it to work, and it was much more clean and simple than using strtok. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`strtok` expects the string you pass it to be a C-style string and end with a NUL (`'\0'`) character.  The string you pass it (`eStr`) does not, so the last call to `strtok` goes past the end of your array resulting in Undefined Behavior.

You need to add one extra character to the size of `eStr`, and set that last character to `'\0'` (or 0).